# Verbo no plural ou singular ao apontar uma alternativa ou outra?

Tags: concordância

Exemplo:

Se o copo ou o pote **for** de vidro, **pode** quebrar facilmente

Se o copo ou o pote **forem** de vidro, **podem** quebrar facilmente

Qual das alternativas está correta?

Neste caso, a frase faz sentido tanto para o copo ser de vidro, o pote, ou ambos, mas e quanto aos casos de ou exclusivo (onde apenas uma alternativa ou outra faz sentido, mas as duas ao mesmo tempo não), a regra continua a mesma?

Answer (score 1):

Se se pensar nas frases deste modo

> O copo ou o pote é de vidro? Se sim, pode quebrar facilmente.
>
> O copo ou o pote são de vidro? Se sim, podem quebrar facilmente.

é visível que a primeira frase é equivalente a «ou o copo ou pote é de vidro? Se sim, pode quebrar facilmente». É o ou exclusivo¹; ex.: «ou faz a lição ou 'tá de castigo» diz que para a pessoal com quem se fala tem apenas duas possibilidades: a) ser castigado e não fazer a lição b) não ser castigado e fazer a lição. Logo, a resposta à frase seria sim em apenas duas situações: a) o copo é de vidro e o pote não é b) o copo não é de vidro e o pote é. Então, se estivermos numa dessas situações «pode quebrar», sujeito indeterminado, mas, por contexto, é lógico assumir que é o objeto que é de vidro. Interessante que depende do contexto; ex.: João fala «posso quebrar com o bastão?» e lhe reponde Carlos «se ou o copo ou o pote for de vidro, pode quebrar facilmente», assim o João poderia quebrar facilmente.

Com a segunda frase, a reposta é sim em apenas três situações: a) o copo é de vidro b) o pote é de vidro c) o copo e o pote são de vidro. Porém, é possível ser sim apenas quando ambos forem de vidro², então, é ambígua. Se for sim apenas naquelas três situações, é possível reescrever como «se o copo e/ou pote forem de vidro [...]»; se for apenas quando ambos forem de vidro, «se (ambos) o corpo e o pote forem de vidro [...]». Em qualquer uma das intenções, se a resposta for sim, é probabilíssimo assumir que tanto o copo quanto o pote podem quebrar facilmente, i.e., se o sujeito da segunda oração for «copo e pote» e a resposta for sim, o copo e o pote podem quebrar facilmente, mesmo se o pote, por exemplo, for de plástico.

De qualquer modo, ambas estão corretas.

1: [https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint54.php#:~:text=3](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint54.php#:%7E:text=3))%20Quando%20os%20n%C3%BAcleos%20do,a%20ess%C3%AAncia%20da%20poesia%20brasileira.

2: [https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/duvidas-sobre-a-conjuncao-ou-e-seu-valor-semantico-e-linguistico/26133#:~:text=%C2%ABOu%20sais%20ou%20entras%C2%BB%3A,pela%20express%C3%A3o%20conjuncional%20e%2Fou.&text=Disjun%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20exclusiva%3A,do%20Sporting%20ou%20do%20Benfica.%C2%BB](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/duvidas-sobre-a-conjuncao-ou-e-seu-valor-semantico-e-linguistico/26133#:%7E:text=%C2%ABOu%20sais%20ou%20entras%C2%BB%3A,pela%20express%C3%A3o%20conjuncional%20e%2Fou.&text=Disjun%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20exclusiva%3A,do%20Sporting%20ou%20do%20Benfica.%C2%BB)

Comment: O teu exemplo-base não é de todo equivalente. O exemplo que dás, «ou faz a lição ou 'tá de castigo», tem um ou a juntar duas frases completas. O da pergunta, «se o copo ou o pote for(em) de vidro, pode(m) quebrar facilmente», liga duas partes incompletas da frase; não se poderia partir a frase pelo ou. Mesmo que (se?) o resto da resposta esteja tecnicamente correta, assenta numa premissa inadequada. Acho que precisas de um exemplo mais adequado.

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil, esse exemplo («ou faz a lição ou 'tá de castigo») é realmente diferente, mas a idéia era só para explicar o ou exclusivo, que é um ou o outro, mas não ambos. Desculpa, mas eu não entendi onde eu separei a frase pelo "ou". Foi nas duas frases no começo?

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, Janilson!
Sim, o verbo aponta se há mais de uma opção. Porém, nos dois exemplos que citou, o verbo deveria estar no singular. Logo, a segunda frase está errada; Por quê? Exatamente porque "OU" é uma conjunção utilizada para "escolher" uma única opção. Já a conjunção "E" dá sentido de soma, fazendo com que a concordância verbal fique no plural.
Exemplos:

- "Se o copo OU o pote FOR de vidro, PODE quebrar facilmente."
- "Se o copo E o pode FOREM de vidro, PODEM quebrar facilmente"

  E há pessoas que, dependendo da frase, preferem unir as duas opções: "Se o copo E/OU o pote FOR(EM) de vidro, PODE(M) quebrar facilmente".

Comment: Oi Julia, perceba que você está considerando apenas o "ou" exclusivo, e ele pode ser inclusivo também: "Se ela se perder ou se o carro quebrar de novo, ela perde a corrida.", aqui, se ela se perder e _também_ tiver uma quebra no carro, ela certamente vai perder a corrida - não faria sentido o "ou" ser exclusivo, já que uma situação não impede nem cancela a outra. Eu diria que no exemplo da pergunta também não. Veja a [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/8513/2764) do Schilive.

Comment: Oi, Schilive! Tudo bem?